# Birthday paradox, huge numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Pick x random "birthdays", say $10^9$. What are the chance of a collision, given $2^{160}$ possible "days"?

I'm trying to estimate the collision rate of sha1 hashes, but the calculation is too big for wolfram alpha.

Comment: You're being a perhaps a little too optimistic expecting that someone trying to break SHA1 would use only $10^9$ combinations.

Comment: It's not really about breaking sha1. It's about the risk of two people having the same hash when hashing some unique input. $10^9$ is just an example of the number of people.

Comment: You could read about the [generalized birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#The_generalized_birthday_problem) and plug in whatever numbers you want.  Note that your number of birthdays should be the number of inputs, not the number of people.  If each of us has a thousand documents, the number of people is trillions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $D$ denote the number of possible days. The probability of a collision for $x$ birthdays is $$1-\prod_{k=1}^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{k}D\right)$$ If $x^2\ll D$, this is roughly $$\frac{x^2}{2D}.$$ For $x=10^9$ and $D=2^{160}\approx10^{48}$, the condition holds and one gets approximately $$10^{-30}$$

Comment: Hi. How do you get to this nifty approximation?

Comment: @rralf Replacing the product by an exponential and using $1-e^{-u}\approx u$ when $u$ is small.

Comment: @Did - I have the impression you're saying there's an intermediate formula, between your two formulas, that has an exponential function. I'd love to see that.

Comment: @BobStein - here's a terrible derivation, where we replace all product terms with the average term which is when `k = x/2` giving `1-(1-x/2D)^x ~ 1-(1-x^2/2D) ~ x^2/2D`

Comment: alternatively assuming `k/D << 1`, we can take the approximation that `(k/D)^2 = 0`, which makes it `1-(1-sum(k/D)) ~ sum(k/D) ~ k*(k-1)/2D ~ k^2/D`

Answer (score 5):

If you have $N$ possible 'dates' and $k$ people, here's one way to get a good estimate for the probability of a collision, especially if $N$ is much larger than $k$:

There are $\begin{pmatrix} k\\2 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{k^2-k}{2}$ pairs of people.  The probability that any given pair of people has different birthdays is $\frac{N-1}{N}$.  Thus the probability of no matches is about $\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^{(k^2-k)/2}$.

For instance in the traditional birthday problem with $N=365$ and $k=23$, the above gives $P(\text{no match })\approx \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{253}\approx .4995$.

Caveat: We don't have exact independence of events, and if $k$ gets close to $N$, the independence approximation becomes worse.

Comment: "The probability that any given pair of people has different birthdays is N−1N. Thus the probability of no matches is about..." This reasoning is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well for those exact numbers you would need to use a computer program. You might wanna try asking the question to a programming stack exchange.

Mathematically we use the same probability.

For the usual birthday problem $P(n) = \prod _ {i=1}^{n-1} (1-\frac{i}{365})$.
Basically for your extended birthday problem you would want to replace $n$ with $10^9$ and replace $365$ with $2^{160}$.

Comment: He is trying to estimate the collision rate of sha1 hashes, but the calculation is too big for wolfram alpha.